# How to recognize and pass over encrypted Email in vba outlook

Tags: vba, encryption, outlook, mailitem

I process (loop over) emails in my folders with vba procedure. in case an email is encrypted, i get the error

[image: > Blockquote]

I want to simply ignore encrypted emails for my processing. I could do the "on error continue", but i'd prefere some

```
if IsEncrypted(mailitem) then
    skip and go to next mailitem
end if
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. any mailitem has the .MessageClass property, which in case of my encrypted emails is "IPM.Note.SMIME". simply checking for this string exactly answers my question

Answer (score 0):

You may check the PR_SECURITY_FLAGS property value.

```
    Const PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003"
    Const SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED As Long = &H1    

    Dim SecFlags As Long

    ' Get current flags value
    SecFlags = oItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS)
```

Read more about that in the [How to sign or encrypt a message programmatically from OOM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dvespa/2009/03/16/how-to-sign-or-encrypt-a-message-programmatically-from-oom/) article.

Please remember that third-party add-ins may encrypt messages without changing the message class or security flags. They will look like a regular email. In that case, you will have to parse the message body to detect them.